# Create temporary object in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

is that possible to create temp object?

the objectwill automatic unset in 10 seconds

maybe i want using something like this

```
var foo = {};
foo[username] = 0;
setTimeout(function () { delete foo[username]; }, 10000);
```

is above code bad for server if using it on 1000 more object?

or someone have a better idea?

Comment: You should have a look at the documentation for the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: The [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator only works on object properties.

Comment: thx, im now realize.
i will using object instead var. edited my question

Comment: does the question is preformance-wise? I'm not understanding you intent correctly

Comment: What is your actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Bergi sorry for bad explanation, i want creating a bot for my server using node-irc. im try to make anti flood, my idea everytime someone chat , my bot will increase that nick property int, so if someone chat more than 5 in 10 seconds, he will get muted

Comment: The code as written will work.  But, it looks like a bad idea for a variety of reasons.  If you can explain what problem you're really trying to solve rather than asking about some hackish-looking solution you dreamed up, then we can have a discussion about whether there are non-hackish ways to solve your problem.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you want "rate limiting" that measures and then controls how often a given user can do something and there are lots of existing code solutions for that depending upon the details of what you want to do.

Comment: @jfriend00 thx for suggestion, now im googling about 'rate limiting'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* create an object that has a property that will automatically set the property back to `undefined` after a specified timeout.

```
function Foo(timeout) {
  var temp;
  var timer;

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'temp', {
    get: function () {
      return temp;
    },
    set: function (value) {
      temp = value;
      timer = setTimeout(this.reset, timeout);
    }
  });

  this.reset = function() { temp = undefined; };
}
```

And then using it would look like:

```
// Console:
> var foo = new Foo(10000); // specifies how long to timeout in ms
> foo.temp // undefined
> foo.temp = 5;
> foo.temp // 5
> // 10 seconds ellapse
> foo.temp // undefined
```

You could also do things like preventing any updates while a value is present or an existing timer is running. It all depends on the design needs.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is looking for. Oh, and setters with side-effects are ugly…